# Series expansion in terms of functions and derivatives

Tags: nonlinear, approximation

I have an expression involving two functions and their derivatives to some powers. I want to obtain a linear expression in functions and their derivatives. How can I do that in Mathematica?

Comment: Can you show an example of what you mean?  Ideally present your expression as Mathematica code so that we can copy and paste it

Comment: @mikado Here is a sample code. 1/(1 + f[x]) + f[t] (1 + f'[t])^2. I tried using Series[expression,{f[t],0,1},{f'[t],0,1}] It worked fine but did not remove the cross terms like f[t] f'[t].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the expression

```
1/(1 + f[t]) + f[t] (1 + f'[t])^2;
```

A series expansion simultaneously in `f` and `f'` will give terms in their product.  A simple approach to dealing with expansions in multiple variables is to introduce a dummy variable e.g. `e`

```
% /. u : (f[t] | f'[t]) -> e u
(* 1/(1 + e f[t]) + e f[t] (1 + e Derivative[1][f][t])^2 *)
```

A series expansion in `e` will then have the desired form

```
Series[%, {e, 0, 2}]
(* SeriesData[e, 0, {1, 0, f[t]^2 + 2 f[t] Derivative[1][f][t]}, 0, 3, 1] *)
```

The dummy variable can be easily eliminated

```
Normal[%] /. e -> 1
(* 1 + f[t]^2 + 2 f[t] Derivative[1][f][t] *)
```